# Chave Composta SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, chave-composta

Estou com a seguinte situação: Tenho uma tabela `ItensVendas` em que preciso aplicar uma chave composta para os campos `VendedorId` e `ProdutoId`, no entanto tenho alguns dados duplicados, ou seja, não consigo aplicar a chave composta a menos que exclua os dados duplicados.

```
|-----------|----------|
 VendedorId   ProdutoId
|-----------|----------|
      1         600
|-----------|----------|
      2         500
|-----------|----------|
      1         600     
|-----------|----------|
      4         600     
|-----------|----------|
```

A consulta que fiz, para trazer os dados duplicados foi essa:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM ITENSVENDA s
JOIN
(
    SELECT VENDEDORID, PRODUTOID
    FROM ITENSVENDA
    GROUP BY VENDEDORID, PRODUTOID
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) t 
ON s.VENDEDORID = t.VENDEDORID AND s.PRODUTOID = t.PRODUTOID
```

Não estou conseguindo deletar os dados duplicados, também não estou tendo a certeza que minha consulta está realmente eficaz.

Comment: Já tentou seu select assim? `SELECT VendedorId,ProdutoId 
FROM ITENSVENDA
GROUP BY ProdutoId
HAVING COUNT(t.VendedorId) > 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sua consulta para identificar os registos duplicados está correcta.

Tem no entanto uma outra alternativa que costuma ter melhor performance: O uso do `ROW_NUMBER().`

Para remover os registos duplicados, garantindo que a tabela irá conter apenas um registo com a chave composta, pode fazer o seguinte:

```
WITH Dups AS 
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY VENDEDORID, PRODUTOID ORDER BY ( SELECT 0)) RN
      FROM ITENSVENDA
)
DELETE FROM Dups
WHERE  RN > 1;
```

Note o uso do `ORDER BY (SELECT 0).` Isto irá permitir, em caso de empate, a selecção aleatória de um registo a manter na tabela. Se a sua tabela tiver uma outra coluna, por examplo, data de modificação, pode usar essa coluna como factor de desempate.

Caso não queira deixar nenhum registo, pode fazer (assumindo que não existem valores nulos na chave composta):

```
DELETE IV
FROM ITENSVENDA IV
INNER JOIN 
(
   SELECT VENDEDORID, PRODUTOID
     FROM ITENSVENDA
    GROUP BY VENDEDORID, PRODUTOID
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS Duplicados 
   ON Duplicados.VENDEDORID = IV.VENDEDORID
  AND Duplicades.PRODUTOID = IV.PRODUTOID
```

Comment: E caso eu não queira deixar nenhum registro. E assim excluir totalmente os duplicados?